# trouble adding multiple objects to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a simple Person class that defines 3 ints for the age, weight, and height of a person. I have used @synthesize to create setter/getter functions for these variables, and the class contains 1 function printInfo that prints out these variables.

```
@import Foundation;

@interface Person : NSObject {
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
}
@property int age, weight, height;
-(void) printInfo;
@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize age, weight, height;

-(void) printInfo {
NSLog(@"This person is %i years old, %i feet tall, and weighs %i pounds", age, height, weight);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argV[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *personBuffer = [[Person alloc] init];
        personBuffer.age = 16;
        personBuffer.weight = 135;
        personBuffer.height = 5;

        NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
        [people addObject:personBuffer];

        personBuffer.age = 20;
        personBuffer.weight = 143;
        personBuffer.height = 5;

        [people addObject: personBuffer];

        for(int i = 0; i < [people count]; ++i) {
            [people[i] printInfo];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, I am trying to make an NSMutableArray of type Person and add objects to it using the Person object personBuffer so that I could have dynamically created people in my program. However, when I run the code, instead of printing out the information for both objects it prints out the information for the second object that I added twice, and I can't figure out why. I did some testing by writing:

```
[people[0] printInfo]
[people[1] printInfo]
```

This printed out the second object twice, so I know that it is a problem with the array itself and not the for loop for printing or the print statements. I think it could be an issue with pointers or maybe memory allocation, as such explicit memory allocation is still a pretty foreign concept for me coming from Python and C++.

Help figuring this out would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** So this is my new code, but I am having more problems:

```
@import Foundation;

@interface Person : NSObject {
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
}
@property int age, weight, height;
-(void) printInfo;

@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize age, weight, height;

-(void) printInfo {
NSLog(@"This person is %i years old, %i feet tall, and weighs %i pounds", age, height, weight);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argV[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        int inputAge, inputWeight, inputHeight;

        NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            Person *personBuffer = [[Person alloc] init];
            scanf("%s", &inputAge);
            personBuffer.age = inputAge;
            scanf("%s", &inputWeight);
            personBuffer.weight = inputWeight;
            scanf("%s", &inputHeight);
            personBuffer.height = inputHeight;
            [people addObject:personBuffer];
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < [people count]; ++i) {
            [people[i] printInfo];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I input values for age, height, etc, the program prints different values than those that I inputted. For example, I entered 2 for the value of age, and the program printed the value 50.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It needs different memory allocation for objects of Person like

```
    Person *personBuffer1 = [[Person alloc] init];
    personBuffer1.age = 16;
    personBuffer1.weight = 135;
    personBuffer1.height = 5;

    NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
    [people addObject:personBuffer1];

    Person *personBuffer2 = [[Person alloc] init];
    personBuffer2.age = 20;
    personBuffer2.weight = 143;
    personBuffer2.height = 5;

    [people addObject: personBuffer2];

    for(int i = 0; i < [people count]; ++i) {
        [people[i] printInfo];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add different Objects of Person Class.
eg.

```
NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];


Person *personBufferOne = [[Person alloc] init];
personBufferOne.age = 16;
personBufferOne.weight = 135;
personBufferOne.height = 5;
[people addObject:personBufferOne];

Person *personBufferTwo = [[Person alloc] init];


personBufferTwo.age = 20;
personBufferTwo.weight = 143;
personBufferTwo.height = 5;

[people addObject: personBufferTwo];

for(int i = 0; i < [people count]; ++i) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Is there a way that I could write a program so that I only need one buffer? The problem I was trying to solve was for dynamic object allocation where you don't know how many objects you are going to need at runtime, so having multiple objects and adding them to the array just defeats the purpose.

Comment: I tried it with a loop, but I got new problems than what I had before. I posted the new code above with my original post.

Comment: You need to give input values. You are not setting age, height in Person Object.